# Python: Download multiple files quickly

Tags: python, multithreading, python-2.7, download, urllib

In Python how can I download a bunch of files quickly? `urllib.urlretrieve()` is very slow, and I'm not very sure how to go about this.

I have a list of 15-20 files to download, and it takes forever just to download one. Each file is about 2-4 mb.

I have never done this before, and I'm not really sure where I should start. Should I use threading and download a few at a time? Or should I use threading to download pieces of each file, but one file at a time, or should I even be using threading?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> urllib.urlretrieve() is very slow

Really? If you've got 15-20 files of 2-4mb each, then I'd just line 'em up and download 'em. The bottle neck is going to be the bandwith for your server and yourself. So IMHO, hardly worth threading or trying anything clever in this case...

Comment: Well I tried using [pyaxel](http://code.google.com/p/pyaxel/) and it was very fast, but after about 20 files it says there's too many open files.

Comment: @yentup might have been worth mentioning that in your question - but I stand by my opinion that a simple loop over the urls to be retrieved and just wait is better... if we're talking 10s of thousands of files (with gigs of data), across multiple pipelines then start looking to worry about it... but until then, I don't feel you have a "problem" as such

Answer (score 1):

One solution (which is not Python specific) is to save the download URLs in another file and download them using a download manager program such as [wget](http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/) or [aria2](http://aria2.sourceforge.net/). You can invoke the download manager from your Python program.

But as @Jon mentioned, this is not really necessary for your case. `urllib.urlretrieve()` is enough for it!

Another option is to use [Mechanize](http://wwwsearch.sourceforge.net/mechanize/) to download the files.

Answer (score 1):

Try using wget module of python. Here is a code snippet.

```
import wget
wget.download(url, out = path)
```

Answer (score 0):

[stream.py](https://github.com/aht/stream.py) is an somewhat experimental, yet cute UI for parallel python (via threads or processes) based on ideas from data flow programming: An URL-retriever is provided in the examples:

- https://github.com/aht/stream.py/blob/master/example/retrieve_urls.py

Since it's short:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

"""
Demonstrate the use of a ThreadPool to simultaneously retrieve web pages.
"""

import urllib2
from stream import ThreadPool

URLs = [
    'http://www.cnn.com/',
    'http://www.bbc.co.uk/',
    'http://www.economist.com/',
    'http://nonexistant.website.at.baddomain/',
    'http://slashdot.org/',
    'http://reddit.com/',
    'http://news.ycombinator.com/',
]

def retrieve(urls, timeout=30):
    for url in urls:
        yield url, urllib2.urlopen(url, timeout=timeout).read()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    retrieved = URLs >> ThreadPool(retrieve, poolsize=4)
    for url, content in retrieved:
        print '%r is %d bytes' % (url, len(content))
    for url, exception in retrieved.failure:
        print '%r failed: %s' % (url, exception)
```

You would just need to replace `urllib2.urlopen(url, timeout=timeout).read()` with `urlretrieve...`.

Comment: Throws an error 'http://www.economist.com/' failed: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'read'